# How to create many build in Testflight for internal testers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an app that shows info about a company using companyId.

Since we are in a testing stage, the companyId is still hardcoded in app.

Now my client wants to have *4 builds (different company each)*.

---

What I've done in Testflight:

> I have uploaded an app with different Build numbers (Build: 1,Build:
>   2,Build: 3 ,Build: 4)

*Result:*

> Only Build 4 (the last uploaded) is received in their email :(

How can I make them received all builds in Testflight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explain to them how to install previous builds like so: -

1. Open TestFlight app
2. Scroll to **Information** part.
3. Click **Previous Builds**
4. Click the desired version.
5. Lastly, click **install** the desired build number.

NB: You have to send a separate email explaining the process and give them version numbers and build numbers you wish them to install.

Comment: When I try to install the other previous build, it only update the currently installed one :( is there a way for them to have a separate build? i mean 4 app, should have 4 icon in my device.

Comment: If the appID is the same I think there is no way to have them install 4 different versions at once. Unless you change the bundle identifier for each individual build and upload 4 different apps with different IDs.

Comment: I see. Actually I'm don't want as much as possible to create new appIDs 'cause of hassle and also different profile for each. But is seems its the only way though. Thanks by the way @MussaCharles. I still upvote your comment.

Comment: Yeah, having them installing one particular version at a time, is the easier option :( 
Btw if this solves(partially solves) your issue would you mind marking the answer as accepted? @PepengHapon

Answer (score 1):

1. Create 4 different Bundle identifier on developer portal.
2. After that create 4 different apps with those bundle identifiers on iTunesConnect.
3. By doing so, you can upload 4 IPA with 4 different bundle Id to Testflight and invite internal testers for all the 4 apps.
4. So testers can install 4 different apps at the same time to his device without replacing previous app.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 4 icons on the homescreen like you said in comments, you need to have different bundle id for each app and then add desired tester to each app. if you only wanna work on single bundle id User @MussaCharles Method

Answer (score 0):

> Since we are in a testing stage, the companyId is still hardcoded in app.

If you’re in a testing stage, you should consider making the company ID and other changeable aspects of the app configurable. It doesn’t take much to add a Settings bundle that includes the configurable options you need, and it’ll let you and your client really test how the app will work.